# dynamic image attachment to phpmailer

Tags: javascript, php, phpmailer, html2canvas

I have html2canvas images dynamically generated and named via the uniqid function. The user creates their image, is sent to a preview screen and confirms the submission. 
I'm having issues getting the html2canvas image attaching to the email being sent. The images are being saved on the server and the emails are sent but the attached image has zero data. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Here's the review and send page:

```
<?php
session_start();

$filteredData=substr($_POST['img_val'], strpos($_POST['img_val'], ",")+1);

$unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

file_put_contents(uniqid() . '.png', $unencodedData);

$_SESSION['question'] = $imgValue;

?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="mailer2.php">
<table width="455" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="175" height="44" align="center"><label for"name">Name</label></td>
    <td width="280"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" />
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="45" align="center"><label for="email">Email</label></td>
    <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="41" align="center"><label for="question">Preview</label></td>
    <td><span name="question" id="question"><?php echo '<img width="500px" src="'.$_POST['img_val'].'" />';
?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="38">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</form>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

...and the sending page:

```
<?php 
session_start();

require_once 'class.phpmailer.php';

$imgValue = $_SESSION['question'];

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$body = "</pre>
<div>";
$body .= "This is the email body text" ;
$body .= "</div>" ;


$mail->AddAddress("michael.y@informinteriors.com");
$mail->Subject = "Endless Configuration Submission";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->AddStringAttachment($imgValue, $imgValue, 'base64', 'image/png');
if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "There was an error sending the message. Please try again.";
exit;
}
echo "Configuration was sent successfully";

?>
```

Comment: In the first snippet you write `$_SESSION['question'] = $imgValue;` and in the second snippet you write `$imgValue = $_SESSION['question'];`, and I don't see an assignment to $imgValue anywhere else?

Comment: Where is your Javascript code ?

Comment: Check your values - be absolutely certain that `$imgValue` actually has what you expect in it, that `addStringAttachment` is returning `true` etc. You're also missing assigning a From address. It also looks like you've based your code on an obsolete example, so make sure you're using the latest version of PHPMailer.